# Command pattern implementation

Tags: java

Recently, I have get familiar with Command Pattern implementation. I have a problem where I need to get a choice for user to select what kind of method to execute typing method name or number, which concerns to this concrete method execution. Everything will be OK if I don't need to create separate class for each method as it describes below:

```
public interface Order {
    void execute ();
}

// Receiver class.
class StockTrade {
    public void buy() {
        System.out.println("You want to buy stocks");
    }
    public void sell() {
        System.out.println("You want to sell stocks ");
    }
}

// Invoker.
class Agent {

    void placeOrder(Order order) {
        order.execute();
    }    
}

//ConcreteCommand Class.
class BuyStockOrder implements Order {

    private StockTrade stock;

    public BuyStockOrder(StockTrade st) {
        stock = st;
    }
    public void execute() {
        stock.buy();
    }
}

//ConcreteCommand Class.
class SellStockOrder implements Order { 
    private StockTrade stock;
    public SellStockOrder (StockTrade st) {
        stock = st;
    }
    public void execute() {
        stock.sell();
    }
}

// Client
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StockTrade stock = new StockTrade();
        BuyStockOrder buyStockOrder = new BuyStockOrder(stock);
        SellStockOrder sellStockOrder = new SellStockOrder(stock);
        Agent agent = new Agent();

        agent.placeOrder(buyStockOrder ); // Buy Shares
        agent.placeOrder(sellStockOrder ); // Sell Shares
    }
}
```

How can I avoid too much class creation for each method that it will be also correct and flexible?

Comment: I believe you haven't understood the purpose of this StackExchange site. We are here to review **your** working code. While it is okay to ask specific focus points in your question, it is not okay to post code that is not yours. I strongly urge you to either write your own code and ask for a review, or to ask this a question on StackOverflow **if** it meets their guidelines.

Comment: I would not ask this question on StackOverflow, but skiwi is correct that on Code Review, the code should be written by you yourself. [See our meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/why-is-only-my-own-written-code-on-topic)

Comment: One moment, I will replace this example by my code from the project. Sorry, for inconvenience.

Comment: @user1376885 - I have locked this question. Please do not update the code with the real code. If you do that, you will invalidate the answers. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Close or delete this question in this case due to I have created a new one -[here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52116/command-pattern-implamentation-avoid-concrete-classes-creation).

Answer (score 3):

I may not be able to review the point you specifically ask for, but I'll go for a general review:

1. Omit `public` and `abstract` keyword from interfaces, it is implicit.
2. Be consistent with spacing out your syntax. You for example have `public abstract void execute ( );`, whereas it should be `void execute();`, some strings in your program also could have spacing fixed.
3. Don't start instance variables with `m_`, perhaps this is common practice from another background, but not in Java. You seem to adhere camelCasing elsewhere though.
4. Make parameters `final` where possible. It gives compiler errors if you accidentally change the primitive or the reference to an object.
5. Use generics, in `Agent` you specify `m_ordersQueue` as `new ArrayList()`, you want to use generics. If all types of objects can be stored, then use `new ArrayList<Object>()`. I see that you have forgotten to declare the type of the variable, using Java 7's *Diamond Operator*, it would be `private final List<Object> ordersQueue = new ArrayList<>();`, also notice that I define only `List<Object>` as type, as you always want to use interfaces to declare types if possible.
6. Give variables descrptive names, `bsc` and `ssc` are not descriptive.
7. Lastly, I would consider using a `Queue<Object>` for the `ordersQueue` in `Agent`, the name implies that you want a queue implementation, yet you are using a list implemention.

The good news is that you seem to be following quite some paradigms correctly and you understand OOP quite reasonably, yet you do need to improve on some points.

Comment: Pardon, I didn't mention that this is just example from [here](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html). I know this minor problems in this example, I just present you idea and what I don't like in this idea. How can I avoid claasses creation for each method execution in my case?

Answer (score 3):

I'll continue where @skiwi left off. Regarding your specific question, there are a few alternatives.

One thing that @skiwi didn't mention though is that you should mark *all methods possible* with `@Override`

One idea would be to use a boolean, but as it is very easy to mixup true and false, I think an enum is better:

```
public enum BuyOrSell { BUY, SELL; }

class BuyOrSellStockOrder implements Order {
    private final StockTrade stock;
    public BuyOrSellStockOrder(StockTrade st, BuyOrSell action) {
        this.stock = st;
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        if (action == BUY)
            stock.buy();
        if (action == SELL)
            stock.sell();
    }
}
```

However, given the big difference between buying and selling, I think you should consider having two different command classes for this. Also, if you start combining different commands into the same class, it will get really messy.

If you're using Java 8, you could have a command like this:

```
class MyCommand implements Order {
    private final Runnable action;

    public MyCommand(Runnable action) {
         this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
         action.run();
    }
}
```

And then you could create commands like this:

```
    MyCommand bsc = new MyCommand(stock::buy);
    MyCommand ssc = new MyCommand(stock::sell);
```

However, although Java 8 is beautiful and nice, I'm not sure if I would recommend using the command pattern like this. I think the command pattern loses a bit of it's point by using method-references.